# Is there any cross reference site for the android OS source codes?

Tags: android, operating-system, lxr

Is there any equivalent cross reference for the open source code of android operating system, such there is for linux ([lxr](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/)) ?

Comment: http://www.linaro.org/ something like this ? what do you mean with "cross reference" ?

Comment: you can search on grepcode.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to  [code4reference.com](http://code4reference.com)

- [Android googlesource.com](http://source.android.com/source/downloading.html)
- [XREF for android](http://androidxref.com/4.1.1/xref/)
- [github repo](https://github.com/android)